# Scaffolding failed! Could not find project file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need support with the Asp.Net Core 5.0 MVC. I have start learning Asp.Net with the Microsoft Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-mac#feedback%22), but when I'm trying to scaffold movie pages with the command

> ***"dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator controller -name MoviesController -m Movie -dc MvcMovieContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers
> --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries -sqlite"***

I received this error :

---

> Scaffolding failed. Could not find project file in
> /Users/usr/Projects/MvcMovie

---

I have also tried to downgrade version of the codegenerator but it doesn't help.

Please advice the solution.

Comment: Could you please share your project structure and class and controller details? How did you added those file and steps need to have a look.

Comment: Is your current directory the one that contains the .csproj ?